# Getting Trojan Warning on use of FileSystemObject

Tags: vb6

I wrote a small program that checks if a drive is available among other things. When I installed it on another computer, Avira Antivirus is popping up a Trojan warning. I narrowed down the problematic lines of code to:

```
20        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
30        FD = fso.driveexists("F")
```

Why would I be getting a warning for that? I'm pretty sure I've used it in the past and have not received warnings. However, I've only used it in DLLs in the past, and this is an EXE File. Is there another way to check for an assigned drive other than using FSO?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get the warning is that the Antivirus program thinks your script is a virus. It goes back to the time when catching a computer virus was as easy as being sent a VBScript in an email (called something like yourbill.pdf.vbs) and then clicking on it. That VBScript would use the FileSystemObject methods to cause damage and general mayhem.

Of course... you could still use the FSO:

```
dim a as string
a = "ting.FileSyst"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scrip"+a+"emObject")
```

Comment: I am speachless: is it so easy to fool an antivirus program?

Comment: If anyone relies on antivirus they are asking for trouble. Vigilance is your greatest weapon.